# undefined symbol uregex_setText_64 sqlite icu extension

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, jupyter, icu, ubuntu-19.04

I'm trying to compile ICU sqlite extension.
System: Ubuntu 19.04
src: sqlite-src-3310100.zip

action history:

```
unzip sqlte-src-3310100.zip
mkdir bld
cd bld
CFLAGS="-O3" ../sqlte-src-3310100/configure && make -j8
# compilation successfull without errors except some warnings
gcc --shared -fPIC -O3 -licui18n -licudata -licuuc -I ./ -I ../src/ext/icu/ -o libSqliteIcu.so ../src/ext/icu/icu.c
# there is no errors
sudo cp libSqliteIcu.so /usr/lib/
```

Trying to load:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.sqlite") # или :memory: чтобы сохранить в RAM
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.load_extension('libSqliteIcu')
```

Error appears:

```
------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-d5ebe36b8718> in <module>
      3 cur = conn.cursor()
      4 conn.enable_load_extension(True)
----> 5 conn.load_extension('libSqliteIcu')

OperationalError: /lib/libSqliteIcu.so: undefined symbol: uregex_setText_64
```

Please help.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580172/sqlite-unable-to-compile-regexp-replace-function-dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Solution:

```
gcc --shared -fPIC -O3 -o libSqliteIcu.so ../src/ext/icu/icu.c -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -L/usr/local/lib
```

Details:

```
pkg-config --libs icu-i18n
```

returns:

```
-licui18n -licuuc -licudata -L/usr/local/lib
```